# prints results only when string item index == list item index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on a little project of mine lately, but I've run into a problem that I'm stuck at. I've already checked various places, but I couldn't really find what I'm looking for. This is my code:

```
special_alphabet = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, 
v, w, x, y, z]

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k','l', 'm', 'n', 
'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

name = input('Please insert your name: ')

item_alphabet = -1
item_special_alphabet = -1
index = -1

for item in name:
    item_alphabet = item_alphabet + 1
    item_special_alphabet = item_special_alphabet + 1
    index = index + 1

    if alphabet[item_alphabet] == name[index]:
        print(special_alphabet[item_special_alphabet])
```

The `special_alphabet` list contains the special characters that I have in variables. I didn't display them because they're too long, but they're there.

The problem I'm having right now is that when I run this code and type in my input, it does actually check the 'name' (string) I've inserted, it just does it in order of the list(alphabet basically). So when I enter: `Amine`, it only returns the special character for A (because it's the first (0) in both the string and the list) and E (same reason, just it's fifth.)

What I'm looking for is how to make it go through the whole list without any order whatsoever and check all the items in it before running the `if` statement and printing out the special characters.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using a dict as lookup instead of 2 lists, where your regular alphabet is the key and special the value.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, yes I definitely didn't think of that, it could be better to organize code and all, but that doesn't really answer my problem... Thanks anyway

Comment: Are you btw looking to only print the "translated" characters, as your example does, or the whole string, but translated? You might be able to replace this with just [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and `str.translate()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I want it to print out the whole string. For example, if I type `Amine`, then I want it to print out the whole string in special characters (A M I N E, something like that). I don't understand really what you meant by mapping, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for these kinds of translation jobs:

```
trans_tab = str.maketrans(dict(zip(alphabet, special_alphabet)))
name = input('Please insert your name: ')
translated_name = name.translate(trans_tab)
print(translated_name)
```

If you pass `str.maketrans()` a single dictionary argument that consists of strings of length 1 as keys and arbitrary length strings as values, it'll build you a translation table usable with `str.translate()`, which creates a new copy of the string where each character has been mapped through the given translation table.

For example:

```
In [15]: trans = str.maketrans({
    ...:     'A': 'A ',
    ...:     'm': 'M ',
    ...:     'i': 'I ',
    ...:     'n': 'N ',
    ...:     'e': 'E '
    ...: })

In [16]: input("> ").translate(trans)
> Amine
Out[16]: 'A M I N E '
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked!! I didn't know any these before, I'll definitely check them out later in details. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

A `dictionary` of alphabet and spacial alphabet may be a best design

in your case try;

```
for item in name:
    ind = alphabet.find(item)
    if ind != -1:
        print(special_alphabet[ind])
```